# Rotate circle by specific angle in animation using WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

I am trying to create an animation where I want to rotate a circle by specific angle while translating.(Basically to create a wheel rolling on a surface). I want to control the angle of rotation of the wheel . How do I achieve this using per frame based animation.

```
    <Window x:Class="WheelOnPath.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1000" Width="1000"   WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Margin="4">
    <Canvas>
        <Path >
            <Path.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush>
                    <GradientStop Color="Purple" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="LightPink" Offset="0.5"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
            <Path.Data>
                <EllipseGeometry x:Name="rotateEllipse" 
                                 RadiusX="90" RadiusY="90"
                                 Center="100,380">

                </EllipseGeometry>
            </Path.Data>
        </Path>
    </Canvas>
</Border>
</Window>
```

Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Threading;

namespace WheelOnPath
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    double time = 0, dt = 0;
    TimeSpan lastRender = new TimeSpan();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lastRender = TimeSpan.FromTicks(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
        CompositionTarget.Rendering += StartRolling;

    }
    private void StartRolling(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        RenderingEventArgs ra = (RenderingEventArgs)e;
        dt = (ra.RenderingTime - lastRender).TotalSeconds;
        lastRender = ra.RenderingTime;
        double x = rotateEllipse.Center.X + 10;
        rotateEllipse.Center = new Point(x, rotateEllipse.Center.Y);
        *RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(45);
        rt.CenterX = 90;
        rt.CenterY = 90;
        rotateEllipse.Transform = rt;*
        time += dt;     
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: RotateTransform rt = new RotateTransform(45);
            rt.CenterX = 90;
            rt.CenterY = 90;
            rotateEllipse.Transform = rt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rotation angle is calculated by dividing the translated path (here in x direction) by the wheel radius.

An easy way to combine translation and rotation is to use a `TransformGroup` with a `RotateTransform` and a `TranslateTransform` for the the Path's `RenderTransform` (instead of setting the center of the EllipseGeometry):

```
<Path>
    <Path.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush>
            <GradientStop Color="Purple" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="LightPink" Offset="0.5"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Path.Fill>
    <Path.Data>
        <EllipseGeometry x:Name="rotateEllipse" RadiusX="90" RadiusY="90"/>
    </Path.Data>
    <Path.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform"/>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" X="100" Y="100"/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Path.RenderTransform>
</Path>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private double startX;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        startX = translateTransform.X;

        CompositionTarget.Rendering += RollWheel;
    }

    private void RollWheel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        translateTransform.X += 1.0; // calculate appropriate time-dependent value here

        rotateTransform.Angle = (translateTransform.X - startX) / rotateEllipse.RadiusX
                              * 360 / Math.PI;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving this idea.